# Why is my custom font not being applied in my NextJS/Tailwind project?

Tags: next.js, fonts, tailwind-css

I am trying to use "Buenos Aires" font for my NextJS/tailwind project. I have multiple .woff files for the font under the following location: /fonts/buenos_aires/[FILE_NAME].

In my global.css, I have:

```
/* styles/globals.css */
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Buenos Aires';
    src: url("../fonts/buenos_aires/AOKBuenosAiresRegular.woff") format('woff');
}
```

my tailwind.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        buenos: ['Buenos Aires', 'sans-serif']
      }
    },
    screens: {
      'xs': '0px',
      'sm': '640px',
      'md': '768px',
      'lg': '1024px',
      'xl': '1280px',
    },
  },
  plugins: [],

}
```

Per usual TailwindCSS fashion, I am just setting the classname="font-buenos".

In my networking tab, I have confirmed that the resource is not being loaded.

Send help pl0x

Comment: Consider adding the path to the file with `className="font-buenos"` to the `content` array. See [Tailwind documentation for configuring `content`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration).